# integrating TRELLO on liferay portlet

Tags: javascript, liferay, trello

i would to see the boards and all Trello cards into portlet Liferay. I have found this code and i can view my boards into my portlet but i'm not able to view the cards. The code is:

```
   var onAuthorize = function() {
    updateLoggedIn();
    $("#output").empty();

   Trello.members.get("me", function(member){
     $("#fullName").text(member.fullName);

        var $boards = $("<select>")
            .text("Loading Boards...")
            .appendTo("#output");

        // Output a list of all of the boards that the member 
        // is assigned to
        Trello.get("/members/me/boards", function(boards) {
            $boards.empty();
            $.each(boards, function(ix, board) {
                $("<option>")
                .attr({href: board.url, target: "trello"})
                .addClass("board")
                .text(board.name)
                .appendTo($boards);
            });  
        });


        var $cards = $("<div>")
            .text("Loading Boards...")
            .appendTo("#outputCards");

        // Output a list of all of the boards that the member 
        // is assigned to based on what they choose in select dropdown
        Trello.get("members/me/cards/", function(cards) {
            $cards.empty();
            $.each(cards, function(ix, card) {
                $("<a>")
                .attr({href: card.url, target: "trello"})
                .addClass("card")
                .text(card.name)
                .appendTo($cards);
            });  
        });


    });

};

var updateLoggedIn = function() {
    var isLoggedIn = Trello.authorized();
    $("#loggedout").toggle(!isLoggedIn);
    $("#loggedin").toggle(isLoggedIn);        
};

var logout = function() {
    Trello.deauthorize();
    updateLoggedIn();
};

Trello.authorize({
    interactive:false,
    success: onAuthorize
});

$("#connectLink")
.click(function(){
    Trello.authorize({
        type: "popup",
        success: onAuthorize
    })
});

$("#disconnect").click(logout);
```

Can someone help me?